# Displaying Posts from Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, query

I'm trying to display posts from regular and custom post types :

```
 <ul class="scroll">
   <?php 
    // the query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=-4,-142,-143,-144' ); ?>

    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <!-- pagination here -->

    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
            <div class="title-block">
                <div class="img-holder"><?php the_post_thumbnail('homepoststhumbnail'); ?><div class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></div></div>

            </div>
            <div class="text"> <?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?><?php the_field('questions'); ?></div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <!-- end of the loop -->

        <!-- pagination here -->

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

        <?php else:  ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting arguments for the main query in your `pre_get_posts` action, and then overwriting that query in the template by calling `query_posts` ([which you should never use](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50762/4771)).

If you want to exclude categories, do that in the same `pre_get_posts` action:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );

function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ){
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'miss_behave', 'emily_davies','gemma_patel','poppy_smythe' ) );
        $query->set( 'category__not_in', array(4, 142, 143, 144) );
    }
}
```

EDIT- using the arguments in an additional query:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => array( 'post', 'miss_behave', 'emily_davies','gemma_patel','poppy_smythe' ),
        'category__not_in' => array(4, 142, 143, 144)
    )
);
```

Comment: Hm, I changed the in pre_get_posts code, and removed query-posts, but not the recent posts section is showing nothing...

Comment: is the recent posts section the main query?

Comment: Not sure what main query is, but I added this '$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );' to the template and now it works. Thanks.

Comment: Ugh, it worked for a second, and now it doesn't...not sure what I did to make it work.

Comment: The main query is the query that is run before the template is loaded, based on the requested URL. Its post or page data gets output via the normal loop within the template. If this is an *additional* query and *not* the main query, you should remove the `pre_get_posts` action, and move those arguments into a call to `WP_Query`.

Comment: I removed pre_get_posts and added WP-Query loop accoring to this article, but the section says there's post (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: there's NO posts

Comment: Edit your question and add the code you are currently using.

Comment: Edited the questions and added the current code.

Comment: you have to set `post_type` as well, see edit above.

Comment: Actually, it does show custom post type posts, but doesn't exclude those categories.

Comment: I think maybe it's because the categories are custom taxonomies...?

Comment: You need to use a [`tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) instead of `category__not_in` for custom taxonomies.

Comment: Please help me with this question too if you could...(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23303539/exclude-custom-taxonomy-terms)